# How to convert a single row into four different columns in jupyter notebook with headers?

Tags: string, pandas, parsing, jupyter-notebook, rows

I have excel file that is a single row. I imported into jupyter notebook and Iam trying to create four columns out of the this row using pandas in jupyter notebook. For example the row:

name: charles

email: char@gmail.com

key: 10223209asd

summary: this is an example

name: brain

email: bria@gmail.com

key: 10390weq09asd

summary: this is an example

I would like the columns to be like this with info in each row.

4 columns:
name             email                 key               summary

1st row:
names: charles  email:char@gmail.com  key: 10223209asd  summary: this is an..

I also have a second file.How do take the two rows and split them into two columns with headers.

email:steven@gmail.com

info: this is an example of an
email. that is more than a sentence 
long.

email:chris@gmail.com

info: this is an example of an
email. that is more than a sentence 
long.

I would like the columns to be like this with info in 2 columns email and info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reshape` with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print (df)
                           col
0                name: charles
1        email: char@gmail.com
2             key: 10223209asd
3  summary: this is an example
4                  name: brain
5        email: bria@gmail.com
6           key: 10390weq09asd
7  summary: this is an example

cols = ['name','email','key','summary']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['col'].values.reshape(-1, 4), columns=cols)
print (df1)
            name                  email                 key  \
0  name: charles  email: char@gmail.com    key: 10223209asd   
1    name: brain  email: bria@gmail.com  key: 10390weq09asd   

                       summary  
0  summary: this is an example  
1  summary: this is an example
```

If want remove values before `:`

```
cols = ['name','email','key','summary']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['col'].str.split(':\s+').str[1].values.reshape(-1, 4), columns=cols)
print (df2)
      name           email            key             summary
0  charles  char@gmail.com    10223209asd  this is an example
1    brain  bria@gmail.com  10390weq09asd  this is an example
```

General solution is create `DataFrame` by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), then count duplicates by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df2 = df['col'].str.split(':\s+', expand=True)
df2.columns = ['key','val']

df2 = df2.set_index([df2.groupby('key').cumcount(), 'key'])['val'].unstack()
print (df2)
key           email            key     name             summary
0    char@gmail.com    10223209asd  charles  this is an example
1    bria@gmail.com  10390weq09asd    brain  this is an example
```

Comment: @steve - My solution working with pandas, so need `df = pd.read_csv(r"\Desktop\Import.txt")` for DataFrame. If there is variable lengths, use last solution. If still some problem, is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59460809/how-to-take-a-list-and-fill-with-values-and-put-into-a-dataframe-and-filter-in-p ...... Can you help with this question. Thank you in advance