# How to take a list and fill with values and put into a dataframe and filter in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

I have a list that has a file name and comes with multiple values for each file. I want to put the data into a data frame and filter.So there's 4 files and values.There should be 5 values each file that start with 'ab ..' or 'uo ..'.However some are missing values that are not there like in file one 'ab +1','co(0)','uo +2.5'.. where 'ab +1','co(0)' is missing 3 additional values. Iam looking to exclude those or fill in values with 0's.

```
values = [
    'file1','ab +5','co(0)','+107','+108','95%','ab +1','co(0)','uo +2.5','co(0)','+107','+107','90%','uo +2.5','co(0)','+107','+110','90%',
    'file2','ab +0.5','co(1)','ab +2.5','co(0)','+106','+102','95%','ab +2.5','co(0)','ab +8.0','co(1)','ab +2.5','co(0)','-106','+102','95%','uo +2.5','co(0)','+107','+107','90%',
    'file3','ab +3','co(0)','+107','+108','85%','co(0)','ab +4','co(0)','+107','+118','95%','uo +12.5','co(0)','+106','+107','90%',
    'file4','ab +3','co(0)','+107','+108','95%','uo +12.5','co(0)','+106','+107','90%'
]

wanted df results:
      0        1     2        3       4      5
0   file1   ab +1   co(0)   +107    +108    95%
1   file1   ab +1   co(0)   nan      nan    nan
2   file1   uo +2.5 co(0)   +107    +107    90%
3   file1   uo +2.5 co(0)   +107    +110    90%
4   file2   ab +0.5 co(1)    nan    nan     nan
5   file2   ab +2.5 co(0)   +106    +102    95%
6   file2   ab +2.5 co(0)   nan     nan     nan
7   file2   ab +8.0 co(1)   nan     nan     nan
8   file2   ab +2.5 co(0)   -106    +102    95%
9   file2   uo +2.5 co(0)   +107    +107    90%
10  file3   ab +3   co(0)   +107    +108    85%
11  file3   ab +4   co(0)   +107    +118    95%
12  file3   uo +12.5co(0)   +106    +107    90%
13  file4   ab +3   co(0)   +107    +108    95%
14  file4   uo +12.5co(0)   +106    +107    90%
```

Comment: That is a lot of questions. Focus on one, try to implement it, then come back and ask if you have problems.

Comment: @wwii main goal is just to get in it a dataframe with filename and the values..

Comment: What about the second part of the comment by @wwii?

Comment: @AMC  for example file 1 find row with min value between col3 and col4 for value ab and uo example SO,row0col3 +107 row0col4 +108 for ab has min value for file1 and row2col3 +107  row0col4 +107 for uo has min value for file1. keep row 0 and row 2

Comment: @devlops_s I’m not sure I understand how that is related to my comment.

Comment: @devlops_s - I am a bit confused. In question is necessary add new rows, in comments is necessary get minimal difference? Can you add expected DataFrame after processing?

Comment: @jezrael just edited question with final results. I am looking to take a list and get the min between col a - col b and put that data into a data frame.

Comment: @jezrael did this help explain?

Comment: Really complicated...

Comment: @jezrael the list is shown in this question. Its appended into the scores list. Maybe theres a better way of doing it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471668/how-to-fix-a-page-loop-in-python-during-webscrapping?noredirect=1#comment105123429_59471668

Answer (score 2):

One convenient data structure to feed to a DataFrame *constructor* is a list of lists where each *sub*list is a row.  So you need to iterate over your values and when you encounter a filename keep it in a variable and use it as the first item of each *sub*list. Make a *sub*list and append to it; if you encounter something that startswith `ab` or `uo` check the *sub*list length and fill it with `np.nan` if appropriate; when *sub*list is full append it to the main list then create a new *sub*list.

- make an empty **main** list
- make an empty **sub** list
- make an empty filename placeholder - `fname`?
- start iterating
- if the item is a filename

  - account for very first filename
  - if **sub** is empty append item in **sub**, assign item to `fname`
  - if item is different than `fname`

    - fill **sub** to length 6, append **sub** to **main**, make a new **sub**
    - append item to **sub**
    - assign item to `fname`
- if it starts with `'ab'` or `'uo'`

  - if length **sub** is < 2 append to **sub**
  - if length **sub** is >= 2, fill **sub** to length 6 and append **sub** to **main**, make a new **sub**
- feed **main** to DataFrame

Comment: @devlops_s That's pretty pseudo.   You asked an algorithmic question.  I may have missed some of the logic.- I'll leave the implementation up to you. If you get stuck with parts of it, come back and ask specific questions - be sure to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky approach that creates a dictionary on the fly and then uses [from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with index orientation to generate the dataframe. Missing values (from the longest file list) will have Nones.

```
values = [
    'file1','ab +5','co(0)','+107','+108','95%','ab +1','co(0)','uo +2.5','co(0)','+107','+107','90%','uo +2.5','co(0)','+107','+110','90%',
    'file2','ab +0.5','co(1)','ab +2.5','co(0)','+106','+102','95%','ab +2.5','co(0)','ab +8.0','co(1)','ab +2.5','co(0)','-106','+102','95%','uo +2.5','co(0)','+107','+107','90%',
    'file3','ab +3','co(0)','+107','+108','85%','co(0)','ab +4','co(0)','+107','+118','95%','uo +12.5','co(0)','+106','+107','90%',
    'file4','ab +3','co(0)','+107','+108','95%','uo +12.5','co(0)','+106','+107','90%'
]



i = 0
value_dict = {}
for j in values:
    if "file" in j:
        i += 1
        value_dict[i] = []
    value_dict[i].append(j)

print(value_dict)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(value_dict, orient="index")
df = df.reset_index() # to get what you wanted in the question
print(df)
```

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: yes ... but filename , 5 values, filename, 5 values, filename, 5 values etc.

Comment: yea I advise you post a few separate questions with each of the technical challenges you are facing. This is too much for a single question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using a list of lists (that now realizing follows a bit from wwii's pseudocode):

```
import pandas as pd

#Initial data
values = [
    'file1','ab +5','co(0)','+107','+108','95%','ab +1','co(0)','uo +2.5','co(0)','+107','+107','90%','uo +2.5','co(0)','+107','+110','90%',
    'file2','ab +0.5','co(1)','ab +2.5','co(0)','+106','+102','95%','ab +2.5','co(0)','ab +8.0','co(1)','ab +2.5','co(0)','-106','+102','95%','uo +2.5','co(0)','+107','+107','90%',
    'file3','ab +3','co(0)','+107','+108','85%','ab +4','co(0)','+107','+118','95%','uo +12.5','co(0)','+106','+107','90%',
    'file4','ab +3','co(0)','+107','+108','95%','uo +12.5','co(0)','+106','+107','90%'
]

data = []
newRow = []
for val in values:
    #Case 1: New file name
    if 'file' in val:
        currVal = val

    #Case 2: Case 'ab' or 'uo'
    elif ('ab' in val) or ('uo' in val):
        while len(newRow) < 6: #length of each row
            newRow.append(0)
        data.append(newRow) #Appending a new row
        newRow = [currVal, val]

    #Case 3: All other data
    else:
        newRow.append(val)

#Configuring final details and converting to a dataframe
data.pop(0)
data.append(newRow)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        0         1      2     3     4    5
0   file1     ab +5  co(0)  +107  +108  95%
1   file1     ab +1  co(0)     0     0    0
2   file1   uo +2.5  co(0)  +107  +107  90%
3   file1   uo +2.5  co(0)  +107  +110  90%
4   file2   ab +0.5  co(1)     0     0    0
5   file2   ab +2.5  co(0)  +106  +102  95%
6   file2   ab +2.5  co(0)     0     0    0
7   file2   ab +8.0  co(1)     0     0    0
8   file2   ab +2.5  co(0)  -106  +102  95%
9   file2   uo +2.5  co(0)  +107  +107  90%
10  file3     ab +3  co(0)  +107  +108  85%
11  file3     ab +4  co(0)  +107  +118  95%
12  file3  uo +12.5  co(0)  +106  +107  90%
13  file4     ab +3  co(0)  +107  +108  95%
14  file4  uo +12.5  co(0)  +106  +107  90%
```

### Assumptions:

- `values` contained an error at index = 46 based on the output given. I've removed it from my `values` dataset.
- All file names will contain the word "file". If this isn't desirable, I suggest gathering a list of your file names and checking whether val is contained in your list.
  e.g.

  ```
  if val in list_of_files:
      ...
  ```
- Values missing will appear sequentially with 0's. So if col 3 is missing from a row but col 4 isn't, the code won't read it as such (instead, col 3 will contain the col 4 data in values but col 4 won't in the dataframe). If this isn't desired, than you may be asking for a more specific/harder problem.
- There will always be "ab" or "ou" in col 1. Cannot go missing. If one plans to change this the problem can't generalize. (You need a second consistent key in your dataset. I chose "ab"/"ou" in this example.)

Answer (score 0):

First Split the original string along the file* values:

```
size=len(values)
idx_list = [idx + 1 for idx, val in
            enumerate(values) if 'file' in val] 
res = [values[i: j] for i, j in
        zip([0] + idx_list, idx_list + 
        ([size] if idx_list[-1] != size else []))]
```

Once the big list is split, assuming no errors, perfect file:

```
#defining function to get list
def getDfList(sList,string,finalList):
    i=0
    for k in range(int(len(sList)/5)):
        i=k*5
        aLine=[string,sList[i],sList[i+1],sList[i+2],sList[i+3],sList[i+4]]
        finalList.append(aLine)
    return finalList

#calling function
makeDf=[]
makeDf=getDfList(res[1],res[0][-1],makeDf)
makeDf=getDfList(res[2],res[1][-1],makeDf)
makeDf=getDfList(res[3],res[2][-1],makeDf)
makeDf=getDfList(res[4],res[3][-1],makeDf)
```

Final step is converting list to dict to df

```
keys=['0','1','2','3','4','5']
df = pd.DataFrame(makeDf,columns = keys)
```

I used to learn python from geek for geeks

I could also put the makeDf section into a function...