# How to fix a page loop in python during webscraping?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping

I am trying to loop through each page but once it gets to the end of the pages it just skips over the needed lines. The pages vary by by link. So I need a dynamic solution for the number of webpages. This a working example so the results will be shown in ran. The stackoverflow requires me to add more details

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"BASKETBALL"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"Europe"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"Euroleague"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"RESULTS"))).click()

allyears=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.main-menu2.main-menu-gray >ul.main-filter a[href^='/basketball/europe/euroleague']")))
allelements=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"td.name.table-participant >a[href^='/basketball/europe/euroleague/']")))
max_page= 10
scores=[]
games=[]
#Get the all year text of link in a list.
alltext=[ele.text for ele in allyears]
allyearslink=[ele.get_attribute('href') for ele in allyears]
for link in allyearslink:
    driver.get(link)

    url = driver.current_url
    print(url)
    for j in range(1, max_page + 1):
        current_page = url + '#/page' + str(j)
        driver.get(current_page)
        print(current_page)
        for i in range(3):
            allelements = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.name.table-participant >a[href^='/basketball/europe/euroleague']")))
            print(allelements[i].text)

            scores.append(allelements[i].text)
            games.append(allelements[i].text)

            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", allelements[i])

            sleep(2)
            elem1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "AH"))).click()
            sleep(2)
            # .date
            date_ofGame = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".date")))
            print(date_ofGame.text)
            elem2 = driver.find_element_by_id("odds-data-table")
            scores.append(date_ofGame.text)
            scores.append(elem2.text)
            driver.back()
            sleep(2)
            driver.back()

results:
https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague/results/
Lyon-Villeurbanne - Alba Berlin
Friday, 20 Dec 2019, 13:45
Valencia - Khimki M.
Thursday, 21 Nov 2019, 14:00
Olimpia Milano - Fenerbahce
Friday, 25 Oct 2019, 13:45
https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague-2018-2019/results/
https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague-2017-2018/results/
https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague-2016-2017/results/
https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague-2015-2016/results/
https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague-2014-2015/results/
https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague-2013-2014/results/
https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague-2012-2013/results/
https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague-2011-2012/results/
etc....
```

desired results:

```
 https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague/results/
        Lyon-Villeurbanne - Alba Berlin
        Friday, 20 Dec 2019, 13:45
        Valencia - Khimki M.
        Thursday, 21 Nov 2019, 14:00
        Olimpia Milano - Fenerbahce
        Friday, 25 Oct 2019, 13:45
    https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague-2018-2019/results/
        Lyon-Villeurbanne - Alba Berlin
        Friday, 20 Dec 2019, 13:45
        Valencia - Khimki M.
        Thursday, 21 Nov 2019, 14:00
        Olimpia Milano - Fenerbahce
        Friday, 25 Oct 2019, 13:45
    https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague-2016-2017/results/
        Lyon-Villeurbanne - Alba Berlin
        Friday, 20 Dec 2019, 13:45
        Valencia - Khimki M.
        Thursday, 21 Nov 2019, 14:00
        Olimpia Milano - Fenerbahce
        Friday, 25 Oct 2019, 13:45
```

Comment: don't swallow the exception

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg where should I place it? or is there a better way?

Comment: Extending on @CoreyGoldberg comment. Swallowing the exception does not help you in anyway. The best way to understand this is a `MemoryError`. If such an error happens one of two things may happen next, either your program crashes or you delete object references so they can be discarded from memory. You could swallow the error, as you are doing, but your program will crash and at that point there will be no indication as to why (the indication was the swallowed exception). So catch only exceptions you are actually doing something with, and consider re-raising that exception.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Iam swallowing the error cause I need the pages to stop at the end and reset starting the next year. When it goes to the next year the page loop doesnt reset. I agree probably not the best approach.

Comment: Then catch a specific error where that should be done and not the base exception. As it is you are dealing with `MemoryError` and every thing else the same way. Actual errors that maybe happening are lost in the void. That is similar to consuming a generator where you should call `next()` until a `StopIteration` is raised; or use a for loop which does that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired output by replacing the loop as below.

```
for link in allyearslink:
    driver.get(link)
    url = driver.current_url
    print(url)
    # click on the last page button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@id='pagination']//span)[last()]").click()
    time.sleep(3) # we can handle this better
    max_page = int(driver.find_element_by_class_name('active-page').text)

    ##################### This is where I believe my problem is at ######################
    for j in range(1, max_page + 1):
        current_page = url + '#/page/' + str(j)
        driver.get(current_page)

        for i in range(3):
            allelements = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.name.table-participant >a[href^='/basketball/europe/euroleague']")))
            print(allelements[i].text)

            scores.append(allelements[i].text)
            games.append(allelements[i].text)

            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", allelements[i])

            time.sleep(2)
            elem1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "AH"))).click()
            time.sleep(2)
            # .date
            date_ofGame = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".date")))
            print(date_ofGame.text)
            elem2 = driver.find_element_by_id("odds-data-table")
            scores.append(date_ofGame.text)
            scores.append(elem2.text)
            driver.back()
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.back()
```

Reason why you are getting error was because of `/` at the end of the `td.name.table-participant >a[href^='/basketball/europe/euroleague/']`.

Here is the sample output:
[image]

Comment: I am erroring out on the page and is there a way to fix max page to the length of the pages needed through a tag? I change the code above to show what iam running

Comment: Do you want to get the number of pages based on the year and iterate through all the pages and get top 3 records from each page?

Comment: for i in range(len(allelements)):.... yes go through all games through all years and all pages available. I was just using range three to test.

Comment: Ok. Let me update the answer based on your clarification.

Comment: then grab the data from asian handicap to put into a dataframe  but the table has missing data. so when appending to list its problematic.

Comment: Iam just trying to get min value for the two odds ratio on the handicap page meaning col1 : +107 col2: +107 .... 107-107 == 0 so min value of odds on that page so I want that row into a df for all years all games all pages.

Comment: Check he updated answer to iterate through number of pages dynamically.

Comment: awesome thank you!!! is there a better to grab the tags from from odds table then grabbing the whole table and appending to a list..... https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/europe/euroleague/zenit-petersburg-crvena-zvezda-mts-dls8FasH/#ah;1 .... Iam looking for min value between the two odds and keeping only that row but currently appending the whole table. I have question related to this here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481315/in-python-using-selenium-how-can-i-extract-text-from-a-class-into-a-df

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204965/discussion-between-supputuri-and-devlops-s).

Comment: I keep getting an error on this...<ipython-input-18-4834face68be> in <module>
     63             # row details
     64             sleep(1)
---> 65             row = rows[min_row_number]
     66             sleep(1)
     67             scores.append(row.text)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType

Comment: I had a question regarding login security. Was looking at a companies web page and they are questioning the devoloper doing the website. I have dont have in depth knowledge of javascript html. However in the page I found this portion of javascript. My question is should this be shown.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get that question.

Comment: So I am working with a company and looking at the login page. In the inspect feature html of the page I notice a portion of there code expose regarding the password and wanted see if this port of code should be expose. Can I send you an email?

Comment: You can join a room and share the details there.

Comment: says I need a higher rep

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211654/discussion-between-devlops-s-and-supputuri).